# Trouble after NERDTree installation using vim8's package manager instead other plugin

Tags: plugin-nerdtree, vim8, packages

I got this strange NERDTree error. The vim distro I am using that fall into this problem install vim using vim8's package manager.

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>42_onNERDTreeInit[1]..<SNR>42_getGitWorkdir[1]..gitstatus#job#Spawn[2]..305:
line   12:
E475: Invalid argument: env
```

NERDTree works. The problem is only this weird message that I see any time I open the editor.

---

Vim version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 21 2019 04:10:35)
```

---

Git version:

```
git version 2.11.0
```

Comment: What version of Vim are you using? What version of git? Assuming you're using an up-to-date version of NERDtree you'll probably want to have fairly up-to-date Vim and git, too. (git because it looks like you have the NERDtree addon [nerdtree-git-plugin](https://github.com/Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin), too)

Comment: (Alternatively, if you're not actually using the git stuff, remove that addon. That will remove the code emitting the error.)

Comment: I've to say that in my host machine does not show this error and I've installed vim 8.2. This error can be visible only in some docker images where, I suppose, I've to update the ide.

Comment: I've also tried to install manually vim inside the docker container but something went wrong (I've just opened a question for this)